# Change presentation of <input> field

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, markup

I have an `<input>` field in a form as below:

```
<input
    class="form-control"
    data-filter="M"
    id="id_options_price"
    name="options_price"
    tabindex="141"
    type="text"
    value="121000.00">
```

How can I change the presentation of the `input`, that allow to display this field on some page as 121 000,00 (with space between digit group) keeping the `value` and `type` attributes as they are.

Is there a way to do it with JS?

Comment: So do you want to show the number in the input field?

Comment: Yes, this number should be in this field on the page

Comment: No...CSS doesn't have this option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is there are some way to do it with JavaScript?"

Supposing it's refering to the object duplication method, yes, i can show you in JQuery.

We only need to insert a new element just after our input :

```
$( "#id_options_price" ).after( "<div class='price'>"+$("#id_options_price").val()+"</div>" );
```

and to hide the original input :

```
$( "#id_options_price" ).hide();
```

Of course, theses line should be called after the page is loaded, i. e. :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $( "#id_options_price" ).after( "<div class='price'>"+$("#id_options_price").val()+"</div>" );
    $( "#id_options_price" ).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution might be obvious AND stupid :
You can use 2 elements to do this.

One input element with "hidden" type and the value for your form. One div element with CSS styling, only for displaying to the user.

I don't think you will be able to modify enough the style of the inputs tag to achieve your aim in pure CSS. As far as I know, inputs as specific elements having some part of their display unstylable.

Edit : As the question slightly changed, this answer might be irrelevant.

Comment: Is there are some way to do it with JavaScript?

Answer (score -1):

Set the input type to "number". This way the number will have a comma instead of a dot, and the browser will automatically convert the comma into dot if needed, for JavaScript for example.

Comment: type field should be of 'text' type

Answer (score -2):

If you wan't to display the number in the input field, you would need the placeholder attribute like so:

```html
<input class="form-control" data-filter="M" id="id_options_price" name="options_price" tabindex="141" type="text" value="121000.00" placeholder="121000.00">
```

Comment: The placeholder won't show because the field has a value.